# Convert InnerHtml values into Decimal

Tags: c#, sql-server, html-agility-pack

Im trying to convert InnerHtml values to Decimal value. The user will input an XPath into **textBox2**

```
List<Decimal> productPriceList = new List<Decimal>();
var priceTags = document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(textBox2.Text);
```

Then I do a foreach loop to iterate though the prices found and add them to a list called **productPriceList**

```
foreach (var prices in priceTags)
{
    label9.Visible = true;
    label9.Text += prices.InnerHtml + "\n";
    productPriceList.Add(prices.InnerHtml);
    label2.Visible = false;
    label3.Visible = false;
}
```

Then I add the values into the **database**:

```
using (var con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    con.Open();
    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(@"INSERT INTO OnlineProductsTemp$(CompetitorID, ProductCode, ProductName, DateCaptured)
        VALUES(@CompetitorID, @ProductCode, @ProductName, @DateCaptured)", con))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@CompetitorID", SqlDbType.Int);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@ProductCode", SqlDbType.VarChar);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@ProductName", SqlDbType.VarChar);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Price", SqlDbType.Decimal);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@DateCaptured", SqlDbType.DateTime);
        for (int i = 0; i < competitorList.Count; i++)
        {
            cmd.Parameters["@CompetitorID"].Value = competitorList[i];
            cmd.Parameters["@ProductCode"].Value = productCodeList[i];
            cmd.Parameters["@ProductName"].Value = productNameList[i];
            cmd.Parameters["@Price"].Value = productPriceList[i];
            cmd.Parameters["@DateCaptured"].Value = dateCapturedList[i];
            int rowsAffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
```

Everything works correctly but I cant seem to find a way to correctly convert InnerHtml values to a Decimal type. Is there a way of achieving this?

Comment: Have you tried with [Decimal.Parse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal.parse(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: I get a error **Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection** when I added a `productPriceList.Add(Decimal.Parse(prices.InnerHtml));` to the foreach loop. This error happens when adding the data to the database and the list has 0 elements within them

Comment: Then it's clear that you should check if you have something in that list, especially when you iterate over an other array/list.

Comment: when i change the `productPriceList` to a string list, it does add elements into the list. But obviously its not converted to decimal. Something seems to be happening to the data when its being parsed to decimal before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your values that come from inner html you can do something like this

```
using (var con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    con.Open();
     using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(@"INSERT INTO     OnlineProductsTemp$(CompetitorID, ProductCode, ProductName, DateCaptured)
    VALUES(@CompetitorID, @ProductCode, @ProductName, @DateCaptured)", con))
    {
         cmd.Parameters.Add("@CompetitorID", SqlDbType.Int);
         cmd.Parameters.Add("@ProductCode", SqlDbType.VarChar);
         cmd.Parameters.Add("@ProductName", SqlDbType.VarChar);
         cmd.Parameters.Add("@Price", SqlDbType.Decimal);
         cmd.Parameters.Add("@DateCaptured", SqlDbType.DateTime);
         for (int i = 0; i < competitorList.Count; i++)
         {
             cmd.Parameters["@CompetitorID"].Value = competitorList[i];
             cmd.Parameters["@ProductCode"].Value = productCodeList[i];
             cmd.Parameters["@ProductName"].Value = productNameList[i];
             cmd.Parameters["@Price"].Value = productPriceList[i];
             cmd.Parameters["@DateCaptured"].Value = dateCapturedList[i];
             int rowsAffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); // also the variable rowsAffected is not visible outside the scope of the for loop
         }
   }
}
```

**Update:**
You should, then, convert the values prior to adding them in the list, like so:

```
foreach (var prices in priceTags)
{
   label9.Visible = true;
   label9.Text += prices.InnerHtml + "\n";
   productPriceList.Add(Decimal.Parse(prices.InnerHtml, <cultureInfoHere>));
   label2.Visible = false;
   label3.Visible = false;
}
```

By doing this you don't have to change the list type.